# How do I change my class?

Tags: planetside-2

In Planetside 2 for PS4, I can't figure out how to change my class. Where do I go or what do I press to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of hard to describe, but in most bases there are stands that have a holographic gun over them and you go there and just pick a new class. X is to go into the menu, R1 & L1 is to change classes, then square to deploy as that class.